# File `SystemDataFlow.eps' not found

Tags: graphics

I am edit tex with texLive2014 and Texstudio.The compiler is:Xelatex.
When i import a eps file,the progrma throw an error:

```
File `SystemDataFlow.eps' not found
```

The package i am using:

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
```

The path:

```
%Set where to find the graphics%
\graphicspath{{./Image/GlobalDesign}}
```

Import picture:

```
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{SingleCodeSpecification.eps}
```

Why can not find the file?this file exists.

Comment: use `\graphicspath{{./Image/GlobalDesign/}}`  with a trailing `/`

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
\graphicspath{{./Image/GlobalDesign/}}
```

with a trailing `/`

Comment: BTW: I was wondering, is the `./` required?

Comment: @daleif it's not required but it means something different if you don't have it. same as `\input{foo}` as opposed to `\input{./foo}` the first is a relative path so searches all directories in TEXINPUTS, the latter is an absolute path where `.` is the absolute path to the main file input to tex.

Comment: I thought `\includegraphics{file}` would first try `file.pdf` (current dir), and then `path/file.pdf`. Does `path/file.pdf` actually find stuff under TEXINPUTS as well? (if the `./` is omitted)

Comment: @daleif yes (the behaviour is exactly same as \input internally \graphicspath just locally sets \input@path and uses the same code as IfFileExists etc)

Comment: I'll make sure to recommend the `./` version.